# How do I convert this python2 statement to python3?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk

I'm trying to update an SSHMenu.py appindicator I was using under Ubuntu 14.04, but doesn't work under 15.04.  I was able to work through most of the other issues in the code until I got to this one function:

```
def add_profile_input(self):
    '''
    Add a 'profile' combobox input to the HostDialog.
    '''
    client = GConf.Client.get_default()
    list_key = '/apps/gnome-terminal/global/profile_list'
    name_key = '/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/%s/visible_name'

    ##  The problem is this line:
    profile_names = [client.get_string(name_key % name) for name in
                  client.get_list(list_key, 'string')]

    self.profile_entry = Gtk.ComboBoxText.new_with_entry()
    self.profile_entry.append_text("<None>")

    for name in profile_names:
        self.profile_entry.append_text(name)

    index = 0
    if self.host.profile != '' and self.host.profile != "<None>":
        index = profile_names.index(self.host.profile) + 1

    self.profile_entry.set_active(index)
    self.add_input('Profile', widget=self.profile_entry)
```

When running the program I get this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/testSSHMenu.py", line 935, in btn_add_pressed
    item = dialog.invoke()
  File "bin/testSSHMenu.py", line 1045, in invoke
    dialog = self.build_dialog()
  File "bin/testSSHMenu.py", line 1118, in build_dialog
    self.add_profile_input()
  File "bin/testSSHMenu.py", line 1171, in add_profile_input
    client.get_list(list_key, 'string')]
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'get_list'
```

It appears that python2/gtk2 has no problem with it, 'get_list' is a defined method, but trying to convert this to python3/gtk3 doesn't work because there is no 'get_list' method.

How do I fix this?  As you can probably tell, I'm a novice with python.

Answer (score 0):

PyGobject (aka PyGI) [does not export a `get_list` interface](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GConf-2.0/classes/Client.html#gconf-client).

You could get a [`GConf.Value`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/GConf-2.0/structs/Value.html#GConf.Value) using [`GConf.Client.get`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GConf-2.0/classes/Client.html#GConf.Client.get) and then get the list using [`GConf.Value.get_list`](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GConf-2.0/structs/Value.html#GConf.Value.get_list).